# Как закрыть полностью модальное окно bootstarp после отправки div блога на печать

Tags: javascript

Есть список ссылок при выборе одной из них открывается блог с формой, при нажатии на submit открывается модальное окно bootstrap, в окне отображается предпросмотрт определенного блога div и button "Print" для печати этого блога и button "cancel". При нажатии на print открывается стандартная страница печати браузера до этого момента все работает, если нажать на print страница идет на печать а модальное окно с пред просмотром не закрывается вообще, даже при клике отмены.

```
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="main-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    ----------------------------------------
     <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="closeModalWindow()"; value="print a div!">Print</button> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Функция для печати:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
function closeModalWindow(){
    printDiv('tmp-1');
    var mainModalWindow=$('#main-modal');
    mainModalWindow.hide();

}
```

Comment: Исходник в студию :)

Comment: $('#myModal').hide(); при это закрывается модальное окно но темный фон не исчезает. Удалил class fade из модального окна. Фон исчезает но при нажатии в главной страничке первоначально нажатой кнопки из списка выходит ошибка, кнопка не реогиркет

Comment: Помогло location.reload(), перзагрузить страничку. Но правильно ли это? В данном этапе это страница не добавлена на проект в SPringBoot, после добавления будит ли это работать и не будит требовать пере авторизацию?

Comment: location.reload() не знаю как поведет себя функция

Comment: попробуй $('#myModal').modal('hide');